# Concrete Sample technologies of Spring To Build Great Applications

Tags: spring

In this Spring Developer [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Spzug_SjJnM), it is stated that Spring helps building robust, reliable, resilient, scalable, and secure application. I can see that the Spring security takes care of the security aspect of an application and the Spring WebFlux helps a resilient application (RSocket also helps in a big deal in the regard. But RSocket isn't a part of Spring). I, however, fail to see how Spring helps building an application which is robust, reliable and scalable, at least directly. For example, in regarding of reliability, a system should continue to work correctly (performing the correct function at the desired level of performance) even in the face of adversity (hardware or software faults, and even human error). How does Spring help in a scenario of hardware or software faults? I really want to persuade our company to use Spring. Can someone shed some light in the regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring it is a framework that help developers to implement more quickly a vast variety of functionalities, but in the end the kind of reliability that you are talking about falls in the hands of the programmer.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The video likely overstates the Spring benefits. If I make a proposal of adopting Spring to my mangers, he won't take any sale jargon, but concrete samples. I am thinking hard to come up materials for the proposal. BTW, I don't know why some people think my question is bad.